# Delphi XE6 - Not finding BPLs in Delphi directory

Tags: delphi, installation, vcl

Win 8.1.  I previously had an old version of D2010.  Uninstalled everything, rebooted, installed Delphi XE6 Professional.  Installing various other packages... Everything appears to be working well.  Tried installing JEDI JCL.  I opened up a command prompt in the JCL directory, and ran install.bat.  After a few moments, I get an error entitled JediInstaller.exe - System Error.  The text of the message is "The program can't start because rtl200.bpl is missing..."

I searched for it, and found it in multiple directories, most notably "C:\Program Files {X86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\bin", so it exists, in a total of 8 places...  Next thought was "Is it in my path?"  I went into Delphi and looked at my Library Path.  It was not there, so I added it, and moved it to the top of my path listing.  I rebooted my computer, just because... I still get the same error.  This made no difference.

I am interpreting this as something is wrong with my Delphi XE6 install, yet many other libraries have installed fine (most notably TMS, which is a large library).

In searching the web, several people complained about Access Violation in rtl200.bpl, but no luck on not being able to FIND rtl200.bpl.  Multiple people have said that they installed JCL fine with XE6.

How do I correct this?  Is this truly a pathing issue? Should I have "C:\Program Files {X86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\bin" in my path or take it out?

Comment: Rob was right...  Tried installing a package via an installer.exe program.  My antivirus kicked in and blocked a portion of the install.  Unfortunately, my PATH was then really messed up...This was what caused my issue.   Had to go back to a backup and start all over...

Comment: Personally I tend to avoid packages. Compile all the code into one executable. Seems much simpler to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some* directory holding that binary should be in your path. However, Delphi's library path is not the path you need to change. The library path controls where Delphi searches for libraries while building your programs, not where Windows searches for libraries while running your programs.

Change your system path.